# The angular controller shows the modal form is valid, when it's not

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a form that's pops in a modal directive (bootstrap UI).
I have 2 input with html5 validation: "required".

In the controller I wanted to find out if the form is valid, then proceed to the server. After I ran into a problem with scopes (when I tried to reffer $scope.FormName.$valid), I found a solution by sending form name with the ng-click.

Then I saw that the controller code shows that the form is valid (even when the required field is empty).
How can I implement check if the form is valid before submitting it.

Here is my code:

**form in html**

```
 <form name="EmailForm"> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1 lbl_hdr">
            date:
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            {{Curr_Date  | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1 lbl_hdr">
                    from:
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <input type="email" required placeholder="email" />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 lbl_hdr">
                    message:
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <textarea class="msg_text" required rows="5"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <button type="submit" ng-click="SendEmail(EmailForm)" class="btn btn-primary btn_padded_top">send</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn_padded_top pull-left" ng-click="$close();">cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**controller**

```
        $scope.openModal = function () {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: '/js/app/templates/msg_modal.html',
            controller: function ($scope) {
                $scope.Curr_Date = new Date();

                $scope.SendEmail = function (EmailForm) {
                    if (EmailForm.$valid) {
                        EmailService.sendEmail("sdsd").success(
                            function (data) {
                            });
                    }//if valid
                };
            },
            size: size
        });
    };
```

"if (EmailForm.$valid)" = always true

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and turns out that the form elements must have `ng-model` in order for the AngularJS validation to kick in.

So just add it to all elements and it should be all good, e.g.

```
<input type="email" required placeholder="email" ng-model="email" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ng-submit` and sending EmailForm.$valid in the arguments.

```
<form name="EmailForm" ng-submit="SendEmail(EmailForm.$valid)"> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1 lbl_hdr">
            date:
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            {{Curr_Date  | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1 lbl_hdr">
                    from:
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <input type="email" required placeholder="email" />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 lbl_hdr">
                    message:
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <textarea class="msg_text" required rows="5"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn_padded_top">send</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn_padded_top pull-left" ng-click="$close();">cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Then:

```
$scope.openModal = function () {
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: '/js/app/templates/msg_modal.html',
    controller: function ($scope) {
        $scope.Curr_Date = new Date();

        $scope.SendEmail = function (isValid) {
            if (isValid) {
                EmailService.sendEmail("sdsd").success(
                    function (data) {
                    });
            }//if valid
        };
    },
    size: size
});
```

};